How do I map a column to create an autoincrement primary key?
My SQLAlchemy 2.0 mapped column with an SQLite database is creating a primary key column due to which I'm not able to insert.
Mode class:
import datetime
from typing import Optional

from sqlalchemy import String, TIMESTAMP, Integer
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql, sqlite
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from typing_extensions import Annotated

timestamp = Annotated[datetime.datetime, mapped_column(nullable=False, server_default=func.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),]


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    type_annotation_map = {datetime.datetime: TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), }


class UserClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[Integer] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    fullname: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    nickname: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(30))
    date: Mapped[datetime.datetime]
    status: Mapped[str]
    created_at: Mapped[timestamp] = mapped_column(server_default=func.UTC_TIMESTAMP())
    updated_at: Mapped[timestamp] = mapped_column(server_default=func.UTC_TIMESTAMP())

Table:
CREATE TABLE user (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    fullname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    nickname VARCHAR(30),
    date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (UTC_TIMESTAMP()) NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (UTC_TIMESTAMP()) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

Insert command:
INSERT INTO user (name, fullname, nickname, date, status, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('John', 'John Doe', 'Johnny', '2024-09-21 19:09:51.484769', 'active', '2024-09-21 19:09:51.490379', '2024-09-21 19:09:51.490400')

When I insert it's giving this error message:

sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.id

I think a primary key needs to be created like this in SQLite: id integer primary key autoincrement. How do I map a column to create the primary key like this?

When I tried to reproduce your issue I got id INTEGER NOT NULL, not id BIGINT NOT NULL, but I also got "sqlite3.OperationalError: unknown function: UTC_TIMESTAMP()"

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlite-auto-incrementing-behavior

You also might need to create a sequence which will be responsible for auto incrimenting:
class UserClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id_seq = sa.Sequence("seq_user_id", metadata=Base.metadata)

    id: Mapped[Integer] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=id_seq.next_value())
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    fullname: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    nickname: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(30))
    date: Mapped[datetime.datetime]
    status: Mapped[str]
    created_at: Mapped[timestamp] = mapped_column(server_default=func.UTC_TIMESTAMP())
    updated_at: Mapped[timestamp] = mapped_column(server_default=func.UTC_TIMESTAMP())

